# What is wrong with this PHP regex to do password validation?

Tags: php, regex

```
ereg("/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z]).{7,19}$/","ABCabc123!!");
```

This is supposed to be a password validator, requiring alphabets in upper and lowercases along with numbers special chars and mininmum length of 8....but the above returns false. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: There are tons of regex tester pages out there. Many will highlight matching portions in your test string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Use `preg_*` instead, and a better validation string

There are (at least) 3 issues with the regex you're using:

1. You're currently needlessly checking for `(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])` when there is a better option to do this - `[\W_]`.
2. You're checking for at least `7` characters and no more than `19`, rather than at least `8`.
3. You're using [a deprecated function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php).
4. Your function allows whitespace in passwords.

This should work better for you:

```
$regex = "/^\S*(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])(?=\S*[\W_])(?=\S{8,})\S*$/";
$valid = (bool) preg_match($regex,$password);
```

Explanation of the components of this regex:

```
/            Delimiter
^            Start of string anchor
\S*          Any string without whitespace
(?=\S*[a-z]) Must contain at least 1 lowercase letter
(?=\S*[A-Z]) Must contain at least 1 uppercase letter
(?=\S*[\d])  Must contain at least 1 digit
(?=\S*[\W_]) Must contain at least 1 special character
             (note: \W will not consider underscore '_' a special character)
(?=\S{8,})   Must contain at least 8 characters
$            End of string anchor
```

**As pointed out by Andy Lester, you may be better off with multiple checks**

As Andy mentioned, you're best off storing a bunch of rules. This allows you to tailor your error messages and add rules easily. In PHP I'd implement this in this way:

```
function validatePassword($password) {
    $rules = array(
        'no_whitespace' => '/^\S*$/',
        'match_upper'   => '/[A-Z]/',
        'match_lower'   => '/[a-z]/',
        'match_number'  => '/\d/',
        'match_special' => '/[\W_]/',
        'length_abv_8'  => '/\S{8,}/'
    );

    $valid = true;
    foreach($rules as $rule) {
        $valid = $valid && (bool) preg_match($rule, $password);
        if($valid !== true) break;
    }

    return (bool) $valid;
}
```

Live demonstration can be found [here](https://eval.in/46915).

Comment: It will fail if the pswd contains an underscore, it is not what the OP wants. `(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])` is mandatory to match special char.

Comment: @M42 Fixed. I even wrote the comment then didn't add the underscore to the capture group for special chars.

Comment: In the first sentence, did you mean to say he should use `preg_match()`?  You certainly aren't using `preg_replace()` yourself.

Answer (score 4):

**Don't try to do it all in one regex.**  Make multiple regex checks.

I know you're writing PHP, but I know Perl better, so follow along and get the idea.

```
my $password_is_valid =
    length($pw) >= 8 &&  # Length >= 8
    ($pw =~ /[a-z]/) &&  # Has lowercase
    ($pw =~ /[A-Z]/) &&  # Has uppercase
    ($pw =~ /\W/);       # Has special character
```

Sure, that takes up five lines instead of one, but in a year when you go back and have to add a new rule, or figure out what the code does, you'll be glad you wrote it that way.  Maybe you require a digit later on.  Easy!

```
my $password_is_valid =
    length($pw) >= 8 &&  # Length >= 8
    ($pw =~ /\d/)    &&  # Has digit
    ($pw =~ /[a-z]/) &&  # Has lowercase
    ($pw =~ /[A-Z]/) &&  # Has uppercase
    ($pw =~ /\W/);       # Has special character
```

Just because you *can* do it in one regex doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: This can also be done in a `foreach` loop with an `array` of validators, and is how I'd normally do it. +1.

Comment: Have added a PHP-esque way of doing this in my answer, credited you.