# Regexp that defines a string with varing number of three different character group

Tags: php, regex

I'm creating in PHP a $pattern for a `preg_match($pattern, $password)` function, and it should be a regexp that defines a string made this way:

- at least `$str_lenght` long AND
- that has at least `$num_capitals` capital letters AND
- that has at least `$num_numerals` numbers AND
- that has at least `$num_symbols` from this range: !@#$%^&*()-+?

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you *need* to use a regex for that?

Comment: Using individual checks would not only be easier, but it would let you tell the user exactly why you're rejecting their password.

Comment: @Robin, i'm open to every solution, but i'm studying how regex works, so i prefer this solution.

Comment: Here, another [example at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/eT1mW8)

Comment: Obligatory link: http://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: Don't do it as a single regex.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18642031/8454

Comment: See also: [Do Strong Web Passwords Accomplish Anything? (PDF)](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/hotsec07/tech/full_papers/florencio/florencio.pdf) For the purpose of learning, this is a pretty good exercise, though :)

Comment: @Jonny5: thx for the example, very interesting.<br/><br/>@Amal: A little bit of irony is welcome, i'm feeling dull & dumb, regex are a subject that teach you humility. thx for the pdf, i'll read it after the coding session<br/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your regex this way using lookaheads:

```
$re = '/(?=(.*?[A-Z]){' . $num_capitals . '})(?=(.*?[0-9]){' . $num_numerals . 
      '})(?=(.*?[!@#$%^&*()+?-]){' . $num_symbols . '}).{' . $str_lenght . ',}/';
```

Comment: Always forget about just doing multiple lookaheads, +1.

Comment: +1. I'd just clean it up a little bit using the HEREDOC syntax, but it doesn't matter much though. :)

Answer (score 1):

*@anubhava greatly destroyed my answer, but I'll leave it for an alternative approach*

`.` matches all characters, `{5,}` repeats it 5+ times. However, since we aren't making one long expression, I would still use the faster [`strlen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php). [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vV0sR6):

```
.{5,}
```

For the rest, I would match a character class and use [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) which will return the total number of matches (may be 0).

Here are the 3 character classes you want:

```
[A-Z]
[0-9] OR \d (\d will match other numeric characters, like Arabic, etc.)
[!@#$%^&*()+?-]
```

An example implementation:

```
$count = preg_match_all('/[A-Z]/', 'FOObar', $matches);
// $count = 3;
```

Please note in the final character class (`[!@#$%^&*()+?-]`), `^` must not come first and `-` must not be in the middle..otherwise you'll need to escape them with `\` because they have special meanings.

Comment: This one is better to track down, why/where the check might fail, like @NiettheDarkAbsol mentioned. Also I like anubhavas single regex.

Comment: Yup, and you can build a Validator Class out of specific rules like this, add multiple rules to a field, and automatically generate an array of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $strRegex = '/((?=.*\d).{'.$num_numerals.'})((?=.*[a-z]).{'.$num_lower.'})((?=.*[A-Z]).{'$num_upper'})((?=.*[@#$%]).{'.$num_symbols.'})/';
```

Or

```
$strRegex = '/((?=.*\d).{'.$num_numerals.'})((?=.*[a-z]).{1,'.$num_lower.'})((?=.*[A-Z]).{'$num_upper'})((?=.*[@#$%]).{'.$num_symbols.'})/';
```

And based on $num_lower you can limit nuber of characters allowed in the password.
And the pass will accept lower case from 1 to $num_lower