# Regular expression for password complexity

Tags: regex

I am trying to implement the enforcement of password complexity through regular expressions on both client (JavaScript) and server side (ASP.NET C#).

The rules are the following:

- Must be 8-40 characters
- Must contain at least one digit
- Must contain at least one lowercase letter
- Must contain at least one uppercase letter
- Must contain at least one special character

Can you please help construct the regular expression needed to validate the above?

Comment: [Relevant xkcd](http://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: Don't try to do it as one regex.  See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18642031/8454

Comment: Don't try it at all. Only password length matters. Make it >= 12 and you're fine.

Comment: @Sam There's always a relevant xkcd =) Awesome

Comment: Can you define what is a special character?

Comment: Follow the rules defined by Stanford University: http://itservices.stanford.edu/service/accounts/passwords/quickguide

Comment: @Sam Changed it to check for length. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this regex here:

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,40})

(           # Start of group
  (?=.*\d)      #   must contains one digit from 0-9
  (?=.*[a-z])       #   must contains one lowercase characters
  (?=.*[A-Z])       #   must contains one uppercase characters
  (?=.*[@#$%])      #   must contains one special symbols in the list "@#$%"
              .     #     match anything with previous condition checking
                {8,40}  #        length at least 8 characters and maximum of 40 
)
```

Comment: Well I was about to say it was not possible with only one regex. Did not thought of lookahead. Nice one.

Comment: You need to add anchors to ensure that there aren't more than 40 characters.

Comment: Your answer definitely works for what I have asked for, and I thank you for your help. I did eventually change my code to just check for a long length requirement as I realized having all these constraints isn't necessarily making it more secure.

Comment: How do I change this to say at least 2 upper case letters?