# My regular expresiion is not working in C#

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I need a regex that checks if a password contains at least one Lowercase letter, at least one Upper case letter, at least two numbers and at least one of(_*&$). This is a MVC project.
This what i have

```cs
[RegularExpression(@"(?=\.\*\\d{2})(?=\./*[a-z])(?=\.\*[A-Z])(?=.*[_*&$])", ErrorMessage = "The password must contain at least 1 letter, 2 digits and a special symbol (_*&$)")]
```

Comment: Probably you have a duplicate here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699919/regular-expression-for-password-complexity

Comment: @Steve There is at least one more issue in this question that is not covered by the above thread.

Comment: Side note: Please don't force users to use _specific_ symbols. Those who use a password manager would hate you. And probably those who don't as well.

Comment: regex101.com is a god send for working with regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with the current regex:

- You escaped `.` and `*`, and now they denote literal `.` and `*` chars, while you wanted to use them as special regex metacharacters
- To match at least two digits, you can't just use a `\d{2}` pattern because it does not match non-consecutive digits, you need `\d.*\d` or a more efficient `(?:\D*\d){2}`
- You are only using lookaheads, non-consuming patterns, but the *RegularExpressionAttribute* requires a full string to match the pattern.

Thus, you need

```cs
@"^(?=(?:\D*\d){2})(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^_*&$]*[_*&$]).*"
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){2})` - two not necessarily consecutive digits
- `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` - at least one lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` - at least one uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?=[^_*&$]*[_*&$])` - at least one special char from the `_*&$` set
- `.*` - the whole string (with no line breaks) (it gets consumed).

Comment: Also, the OP is double-escaping `\\d` even though they're using the verbatim identifier (I know you fixed it in the new pattern but it's worth pointing out).