# How to require some characters and restrict others with Regex in HTML input pattern

Tags: html, regex, input

As a user is typing their new password, I want them to be able to see if their password meets the requirements or not. I have a Regex pattern set up inside the input tag, and if the requirements aren't met, the input box is outlined in red and the form can't be submitted. This looks like:

`<input type="password" pattern="((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.[!@@#$%&?]).{8,32})" placeholder="Password" required />`

I adapted that pattern from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23700041/10172129). I have it so that the user's password must contain 8-32 characters, one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one special character (!@#$%&?), and one number, and that works fine. However, I also want to exclude some special characters from the input, for example, the semicolon (;). I have tried adding `(?!.[;])` like so:

`((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.[!@@#$%&?])(?!.[;]).{8,32})`

This breaks the entire pattern, though. Could someone explain what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it? Or would it be better to do this manually by using a Javascript listener to check if the password meets the requirements each time the user does a keypress?

Comment: Try: `(?!.*[;])` instead - note the star (`*`). It's like you have with positive look ahead. You can add more character inside the square brackets, like `[;abc]` will 'ban' the characters `;abc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@@#$%&?])(?!.*[;]).{8,32})
```

Fine-tunings from your regex:

1. Added back an asterisk `*` to the positive lookahead for symbols list `[!@@#$%&?]`
2. Added back an asterisk `*` to the negative lookahead for symbol `[;]`

You need an asterisk `*` after the dot `.` in order to allow matching of multiple characters (by `*`) for any character (by `.`).  Otherwise, your regex allows only ONE single character before the symbols to include and exclude.