# Get each item from list to check if it is in password, but without for loop

Tags: python

I want to make a password validator. When a user types a password, it will check for some special characters and numbers and length.

Conditions:

1. At least 1 letter between [a-z] and 1 letter between [A-Z].
2. At least 1 number between [0-9].
3. At least 1 character from [$#@].
4. Minimum length 6 characters.
5. Maximum length 16 characters.

My code:

```py
special_char = ['$', '#', '&', '@', '!']
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

print('Type a new password:-')
password = input('Password: ')

if len(password) > 5 and len(password) < 16:
  if special_char in password:
    if nums in password:
      print('Your password is strong enough.')
```

Output and Error:

```py
Type a new password:-
Password:  arya90#se

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/52d06fa3d8741730/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    if special_char in password:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

My questions:

1. What do I do to check if there are numbers and special characters in the password? The numbers and special characters should be from that list.
2. What is the shortest way to check the password is valid or not? Means how to find if there are any special characters in the password or not? Even if it is not in the list?

Last condition:

I want just simple python code, with `if` `else` statements, etc. I don't want any modules like random regex or math.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression for password complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699919/regular-expression-for-password-complexity)

Comment: But it is regex, it just want simple python code without importing any module. By the way thanks for the link.

Comment: You said that you don't want to use for loop. That is it. Where does question says no regex? Also, why do you think it is bad to rely on modules?

Comment: Sorry but now I have edited my answer.

Comment: You need a module ```re``` to achieve this.

Comment: You can use methods like isalphanum to check if the password is alphanumeric. Length should be easy with `len(password)`

Comment: Ok, thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can

- use `set` to check if there are numbers and special characters in the password
- use `not .islower()` and `not .isupper()` to check for at least 1 capital and at least 1 small letter.
  Since the `islower()` method returns `False` if the string contains at least one uppercase alphabet.

code:

```
special_char = set(['$', '#', '&', '@', '!'])
nums = set(map(str, range(10)))

print('Type a new password:-')
password = input('Password: ')

if len(password) > 5 and len(password) < 16 and special_char & set(password) and nums & set(password) and (not password.islower()) and (not password.isupper()):
    print('Your password is strong enough.')
else:
    print('Your password is not strong enough.')
```

result:

```
Type a new password:-
Password: arya90#sE
Your password is strong enough.

Type a new password:-
Password: 12345678
Your password is not strong enough.

Type a new password:-
Password: $$$$$$
Your password is not strong enough.

Type a new password:-
Password: arya90#se
Your password is not strong enough.

Type a new password:-
Password: ARRY90#SE
Your password is not strong enough.
```

Comment: And what if I want to check for at least 1 capital and at least 1 small letter?

Comment: Thank you sooo much, definetly I will give an upvote and tick mark.

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

print('Type a new password:-')
password = input('Password: ')

if len(password) > 5 and len(password) < 16:
  if re.search('[$#&@]',password) is not None:
    if re.search('[0-9]',password) is not None:
      print('Your password is strong enough.')
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I had mentioned that I don't want to use any modules

Comment: `Simple is better than complex.`
I think this is simple!