# Regular Expression such that Should contain atleast one uppercase , one lower case , one numeric and one special character - either $,!,@ or # only

Tags: regex

Right now I am able to write `^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$!@#]).*$` but the problem is, it accepts all other special character also I just want it to accept `$!@#`

Comment: Don't try to do do all your password validation in one regex.  Do multiple checks both for readability and future maintenance.  See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641012/what-is-wrong-with-this-php-regex-to-do-password-validation/18642031#18642031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$!@#])[$!@#a-zA-Z\d]{6,}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zD7uO3/5)

Comment: Same Problem it is accepting all other special characters also, It must contain a special character but no other special character other than $!@# should be allowed

Comment: it is accepting abcD1@. or Abc1#) also, it should not allow any other special character other than $!@#